# How do I get a list of questions that are eligible for deletion?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When a question gets closed, I have to wait two days before I can vote to delete, which is fine, but it would be nice if those questions appeared on a list in moderator tools after two days, so I could find them again.

EDIT: I've spoken with Mark Trapp, a moderator on Programmers.SE, and he says that his community's participation on delete votes is very close to zero.  I believe that is because users do not have a way to easily see those questions that are eligible for deletion votes.

Comment: I sometimes use [search "closed:1", sort by activity, go to page 10](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=10&tab=active&q=closed%3a1) for this. If you combine this with a tag search, you don't have to go that much back.

Answer (score 2):

Go about 10 pages back on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-closed

(or the Serverfault/SuperUser equivilant)

Migrated questions are not eligible for deletion by the way.

Jeff needs to add something that filters out the migrated questions along with questions that aren't passed the 4 day deadline. But until then.

Comment: on superuser it's more like "go back 1 page" ... :)

Comment: I don't think the average user will bother with this. It's a good tool for moderators, when they have nothing better to do, but not for the community at large, IMO. It lacks the quality of being clear, obvious and easy to do.

Comment: Note that your link no longer works.  The closest equivalent seems to be http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=last2days, but it no longer goes far enough back to get the ones that are two days old.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that there should be a one-stop list of questions eligible for deletion.

As a recent 10K user (meta), I'm still struggling a bit as to what a *conscientious* 10K user, interested in helping out the site, should do. There's a lot of *"look-but-don't-touch"* reports.

**Deleting closed posts is a good candidate** and should be surfaced as an obvious 10K moderator activity. But there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this. A simple "Closed Questions Eligible for Deletion" report should be a tab or at least at the top of some list somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The "[Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days)" tab will show you the questions with the highest number of delete votes. That won't show you all the closed questions that are eligible for deletion, but it's a pretty good start.